# Using IDLocaltion Attribute in a cache sql storage map

Tags: intersystems-cache

I have an Index global (XWES.ETI) that I want to use to pull subscripts for anther table. The XWES.ETI global has a single subscript (a sequentional number) and has two pieces of data that I want to use as subscripts for actual global defined in the cache sql storage map (^ZIDETRP).  My class compiles without error but won't load and gets an error in %AcquireLock because one my created variables (edt) is undefined.  I know this code is close but I just can't seem to spot the issue.  Suggestions anyone? The class is as follows:

```
Class System.ErrTest Extends (%Persistent, %XML.Adaptor) [ StorageStrategy = Legacy ] 
{

Property ErrID As %Library.Integer;

Property ErrDt As %Library.Date;

Property ErrNum As %Library.Integer;

Property EDat As %Library.String;

///  Index iMaster on ErrID [IDKey,Unique]; 
Index iMaster On ErrID [ IdKey, Unique ];

<Storage name="Legacy"> 
  <ExtentSize>100000</ExtentSize> 
  <IdLocation>^XWES.ETI</IdLocation> 
  <SequenceNumber>6</SequenceNumber> 
<SQLMap name="Map1"> 
  <Data name="EDat"> 
   <Delimiter>$c(0)</Delimiter> 
   <Node>1</Node> 
   <Piece>1</Piece> 
  </Data> 
  <Data name="ErrDt"> 
   <RetrievalCode> Set {*}=edt</RetrievalCode> 
  </Data> 
  <Data name="ErrNum"> 
   <RetrievalCode> Set {*}=enum</RetrievalCode> 
   </Data> 
 <Global>^ZIDETRAP</Global> 
 <RowReference>^ZIDETRAP(edt,enum)</RowReference> 
 <Subscript name="1"> 
   <AccessType>Other</AccessType> 
   <Accessvar name="1"> 
     <Code> S edt=$p(^XWES.ETI({L1}),"^",1)</Code> 
     <Variable>edt</Variable> 
   </Accessvar> 
   <Accessvar name="2"> 
     <Code> S enum=$p(^XWES.ETI({L1}),"^",2)</Code> 
     <Variable>enum</Variable> 
   </Accessvar> 
   <Expression>{ErrID}</Expression> 
   <NextCode> s {L1}=$Order(^XWES.ETI({L1}))</NextCode> 
 </Subscript> 
<Type>data</Type> 
</SQLMap> 
<StreamLocation>^WSandlin.System.ErrTestS</StreamLocation> 
<Type>%CacheSQLStorage</Type> 
</Storage> 
}
```

Comment: Is this just an example or is this your actual situation? Why not just use piece access to set those fields based on the current subscript? I think you're making things more complicated than they need to be, what you're doing can all be done more simply with straightforward piece access. Why do you need to access ^ZIDETRAP at all?  You might contact InterSystems support and ask for the Two Global storage example if your actual situation is more complicated than this.

Comment: This is an actual situation.  The XWES.ETI global is just an index into the ZIDETRAP global.  I'm using it to get the two subscripts I need.  All of the data that I'm going to have as properties of this class is in the ZIDETRAP global.  I'm not quite sure how you would like me to simplify it.  Can you write out what you think would work here?  Thanks

Comment: Ah... from your response you're saying there are other properties that need to be accessed from ^ZIDETRAP. This means there is more to the problem than the example you've provided (which only contains references to properties in your ^XWES.ETI "index" global). I think this is a classic Two Global scenario. Let us know if psr's solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this with data, but the %AquireLock issue goes away because it is a read-only mapping.  It's kind of a hack but it might work or help and it's way too long for a comment.

```
{

Property ErrID As %Library.Integer;

Property ErrDt As %Library.Date;

Property ErrNum As %Library.Integer;

Property EDat As %Library.String;

///  Index iMaster on ErrID [IDKey,Unique]; 
Index iMaster On (ErrID, ErrDt, ErrNum) [ IdKey, Unique ];

<Storage name="Legacy">
<ExtentSize>100000</ExtentSize>
<IdLocation>^XWES.ETI</IdLocation>
<SequenceNumber>6</SequenceNumber>
<SQLMap name="Map1">
<Data name="EDat">
<Delimiter>$c(0)</Delimiter>
<Node>1</Node>
<Piece>1</Piece>
</Data>
<Global>^ZIDETRAP</Global>
<RowIdSpec name="1">
<Expression>{ErrID}</Expression>
<Field>ErrID</Field>
</RowIdSpec>
<RowIdSpec name="2">
<Expression>$P(^XWES.ETI({ErrID}),"^",1)</Expression>
<Field>ErrDt</Field>
</RowIdSpec>
<RowIdSpec name="3">
<Expression>$P(^XWES.ETI({ErrID}),"^",2)</Expression>
<Field>ErrNum</Field>
</RowIdSpec>
<Subscript name="1">
<Expression>{ErrID}</Expression>
<NextCode>s {L1}=$Order(^XWES.ETI({L1}))</NextCode>
</Subscript>
<Subscript name="2">
<AccessType>Other</AccessType>
<DataAccess>$p(^XWES.ETI({L1}),"^",1)</DataAccess>
<Expression>{ErrDt}</Expression>
<NextCode>S {L2}=""</NextCode>
<StopExpression>1</StopExpression>
</Subscript>
<Subscript name="3">
<AccessType>Other</AccessType>
<DataAccess>$p(^XWES.ETI({L1}),"^",1)</DataAccess>
<Expression>{ErrNum}</Expression>
<NextCode>S {L3}=""</NextCode>
<StopExpression>1</StopExpression>
</Subscript>
<Type>data</Type>
</SQLMap>
<StreamLocation>^WSandlin.System.ErrTestS</StreamLocation>
<Type>%CacheSQLStorage</Type>
</Storage>
}
```